# Error serving CSS file via CloudFront, works fine directly from origin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, amazon-cloudfront

I'm running a Rails 3.2 app on Heroku via the custom domain www.shmocket.com. I set up a CloudFront distribution with www.shmocket.com as the only origin. It's alternate domain name is `cdn.shmocket.com`, which is simply configured as a CNAME for the CloudFront distribution's URL `d3n87gn5nko8eq.cloudfront.net`.

When I request an asset via CloudFront, the Rails app gives me an error:

```
> curl http://cdn.shmocket.com/assets/application-dce210940d2cd3c699c4809800ae2f0b.css

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD><TITLE>Internal Server Error</TITLE></HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1>Internal Server Error</H1>
    undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
    <HR>
    <ADDRESS>
     WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2012-04-20) at
     www.shmocket.com:80
    </ADDRESS>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
curl: (18) transfer closed with 100318 bytes remaining to read
```

In the Rails log file:

```
2012-09-11T06:53:28+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-09-11 06:53:28] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
2012-09-11T06:53:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:71:in `service'
2012-09-11T06:53:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2012-09-11T06:53:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2012-09-11T06:53:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
2012-09-11T06:53:28+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.shmocket.com/assets/application-dce210940d2cd3c699c4809800ae2f0b.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=18ms status=500 bytes=325
```

Accessing http://www.shmocket.com/assets/application-dce210940d2cd3c699c4809800ae2f0b.css directly works fine.

The same error happens when using the real CloudFront domain, i.e. http://d3n87gn5nko8eq.cloudfront.net/assets/application-dce210940d2cd3c699c4809800ae2f0b.css

CloudFront config:

http://screencast.com/t/A62AKBGX
http://screencast.com/t/u9Grgj5i
http://screencast.com/t/vzRduwxor50v

Quite honestly I'm stumped and don't know what could cause this at all. I'm suspecting it's something obvious I'm overlooking...

Any suggestions are appreciated...

EDIT:

It has been suggested that some middleware reacts weirdly to the headers CloudFront sends. I don't include any middleware manually and checked the list of used gems, nothing I could see there either:

```
source :rubygems

ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.8'
gem 'haml', '~> 3.2.0.beta.3'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'slim_migrations', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'redis', '~> 2.2.2'
gem 'redis-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'memoizer', '~> 1.0.1'
gem 'marginalia', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'awesome_print', '~> 1.0.2'
gem 'log_buddy', '~> 0.7.0'
gem 'squeel', '~> 1.0.9'
gem 'airbrake', '~> 3.1.2'
gem 'httparty', '~> 0.8.3'
gem 'ember-rails', '~> 0.7.0'

group :assets do
  gem 'oily_png', '~> 1.0.2'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', github: 'dszczyt/bootstrap-sass'
  gem 'font_awesome', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.5'
  gem 'compass-rails', '~> 1.0.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '~> 1.2.7'
end

group :development do
  gem 'heroku', '~> 2.30.5'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.5.0'
  gem 'foreman', '~> 0.57.0'
  gem 'quiet_assets', '~> 1.0.1'
  gem 'sextant', '~> 0.1.3'
  gem 'right_aws', '~> 3.0.4'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.12b4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.14.0'
end
```

Comment: I am also getting the same error when accessing the "real file" on shmocket.com - can you check again?

Comment: Do you have some middleware that might be behaving differently with the set of headers cloudfront sends?

Comment: @j0nes Extremely weird... the real file works fine for me.

Comment: @FrederickCheung I'm only using gems I used on multiple other projects, "ember-rails" being the only exception, and it doesn't seem to do anything weird. I'll post my Gemfile in the original post.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's an issue w/ Heroku's Rack::Cache + the Dalli gem
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8366

Disabling Rack::Cache from loading in production.rb fixed the issue:

```
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = nil
```